# Condition For json Array via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I'm Parsing This json Array and I Want to Take `text` Object of `answer` and Put That in New Column `awnser2`, and This is **one Row** of My json Rows,
answer 38 and 39 in json Are Same as `text` But anser 40 Is Descriptive Awnser, I Got Illegal string offset 'text' for **Hello Word**, How Can I Make a Condition to Have Both of Them in Output?

```
[{"id":"38","answer":[{"option":"3","text":"HIGH"}],"type":"a"},
 {"id":"39","answer":[{"option":"3","text":"LOW"}],"type":"b"},
 {"id":"40","answer":["Hello Word"],"type":"c"}]
```

This Is My Code:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","array");
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

$sql="SELECT `survey_answers`,us_id FROM `user_survey_start`";
if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
        $json = $row[0];
        if(!is_null($json)){                          

    $json = preg_replace('/\r|\n/','\n',trim($json));   
    $jason_array = json_decode($json,true);
 $answers = array();
            foreach ($jason_array as $data) {
                    if (array_key_exists('answer', $data)) {   
                        foreach($data['answer'] as $ans){
                                $answers[] =$ans['text'] ;
                        }
                    }
            }
            if(!empty($answers)) {
             $answers= implode('',$answers); /// implode yes if you got values
            } 
            else { 
                $answers = 'Nothing Find'; //blank if not have any values
            }
            $sql3="update user_survey_start set awnser2='$answers' where us_id=".$row[1];//run update sql
            echo $sql3."<br>";
            mysqli_query($con,$sql3);
        }
    }
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I Want to Have `text of Awnser:` for ....to 39 and `Awnser:` for 40 , 40 is last awnser

Comment: Your `Hello World` is not in JSONArray like the previous two.

Comment: I Know I Want `text of Awnser:` for 38 and 39 and `Awnser:` for 40 , 40 is last awnser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check key is set or not otherwise assign value

```
foreach ($jason_array as $data) {
                    if (array_key_exists('answer', $data)) {   
                        foreach($data['answer'] as $ans){
                              $answers[] = isset($ans['text']) ? $ans['text'] : $ans;                                
                        }
                    }
            }
```

Comment: Solved,Greaaaaaaaaaat, You Are Very Intelligent,